# How to convert string date 11:01 PM - 11 Aug 2009 dateTime object - Python 3

Tags: django, python-3.x, datetime

Im trying to convert a string date "11:01 PM - 11 Aug 2009" into a `datetime` object in python. My code is:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('11:01 PM - 11 Aug 2009', '%I:%M %p - %d %B %Y')
```

but I am getting an error: `time data '11:01 PM - 11 Aug 2009' does not match format '%I:%M %p - %d %B %Y'`

Not sure what I've missed.

Answer (score 0):

the issue was the month is short form so sept instead of september. Had to change it to be `%b` instead of `%B`.

Updated code is:

```
from datetime import datetime
datetime.strptime('11:01 PM - 11 Aug 2009', '%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
datetime.strptime('11:01 PM - 11 Aug 2009', '%I:%M %p - %d %b %Y')
```

%b  Month as locale’s abbreviated name. 
Jan, Feb, ..., Dec (en_US);
Jan, Feb, ..., Dez (de_DE)

For reference: 
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior